# How to polish carbon frames?

Tags: carbon, paint

My carbon frame has some slight scratches and some black gunk around the seat stays. What is the best way to polish the frame to bring it back to its original appearance?

I was thinking of using a solvent to remove the black scuff marks and a 1200 wet-n-dry emory paper with water to gently polish the duco back, finishing it with a gentle buff and polish.

Someone here reckons the car polishing products are just as good.

Any thoughts on this please?

**UPDATE**: Yes I have tried the damp cloth trick already. No good once it dries.

Thanks

Comment: Check your manual, but have you tried just wiping it down with a damp cloth? I'd avoid the emory paper and solvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Using polishing compound **WARNING: if this is your first time tinker with carbon fiber composite, I would recommend you to read up carefully, beside from my general guide in here.**

   a) Use sand paper to **lightly** sand down the scuff. Make sure you do not sand into the carbon fiber. The sanding would produce black powder if you make this mistake.

   b) Apply polishing cream/grease to make the surface shiny, with a cloth.

   **Advantage**: i) stress-free, ii) simple and quick iii) cheap

   **Disadvantage**: i) might require you to re-apply the polishing compound ever 3-6 months.
2. Using epoxy (cold setting, Bisphenol-A-Diglycidylether + Triethylenetetramine)

   Preparation: Epoxy resin and hardener, release film (or alternatively, electrical tape)

   a) sand down lightly. Do not sand into the carbon fiber.

   b) Tape around the tube for both ends of the fixing area, approximately 1.0 cm away from the sanded area.

   c) Apply the epoxy. Do not smear the epoxy yet.

   d) Apply release film/electrical tape and use pressure to smear the epoxy over the surface.

   **Advantage**: i) gives a very shiny surface if done correctly, ii) permanent surface

   **Disadvantage**: i) moderately difficult task, ii) expensive and arduous project